# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(2\pi\cdot n!\cdot e)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(2\pi\cdot n!\cdot e)$$

I can't think of a theorem to solve this. I think first we have to convert it into the form of standard limit. Also by just putting $\infty$ into the limit we get $$\sin(\infty)$$ which I think is indeterminate. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "convert it into the form of standard limit " What do you mean by that?

Comment: like we have a $$\lim_{n\rightarrow a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=na^{n-1}$$ this is just an example of a standard limit....i meant something like that

Comment: I don't think, in this form, it is solvable by standard limits. Are you sure for the given expression?

Comment: In my opinion, it is really an undetermined limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
$$n!e =n!\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$$
and so it equals an integer plus
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n!}{k!}=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+....$$
Since $\sin(x)=\sin(x+2m\pi)$ for any $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, using the monotonicity of $\sin$ in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and the estimates
$$\frac{1}{n+1} < \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n!}{k!} < \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^{k-n}}=\frac{n+1}{n}-1=\frac{1}{n}$$
we conclude that
$$\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n+1})< \sin(2\pi n!e) < \sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})$$
and so by confrontation the limit is $0$

Comment: Nice answer, I like it very much !

Comment: when you did $$n!\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$$ shouldn't this come $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{k!}$$  and not $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{k!}$$ How did you come with that??

Comment: Read carefully. I didn't say that these two quantities are equal. I said that their difference is an integer

Comment: @DarkMagician can you pls add why?

Comment: Of course. Their difference is $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}$$ and $k!$ divides $n!$ if $k\leq n$